# Spotfire US / UK datetime formats

Tags: spotfire

I have an excel data file which contains several datetime columns in US date format - mm/dd/yy hh:mm.  I would like to use this as a data table, but work with the data in a UK date format - dd/mm/yy hh:mm.  Ideally, I would like to keep the original excel data intact and use the data in Spotfire as DateTime.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: A datetime is just a number, it is only when it is displayed that you see a string formatted like "12/25/2016" or "25/12/2016", so it should simply work as-is. Never try working with dates as strings for anything other than processing text input to a datetime or formatting a datetime to a string for display - it will only cause grief. All intermediate processing should be done as a datetime.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't think the OP wanted to change the datatype, only the presentation of the date in the presentation layer (Spotfire).

Comment: @scsimon I was under the impression that the OP thinks that a datetime has a format. Let's wait and see what they say :)

Comment: Ah that's a fair point @AndrewMorton

Comment: Thank you both - I've been wresting with the source XLS, which was not really in proper datetime format it would seem. I couldn't get anything to work, so I have ended up splitting the date and the time from the single column into two in excel, then reformatting the date part to UK - then loading to Spotfire and concatenating the UK date and time back together in a single datetime value. Thankfully, the data refresh is not too frequent.

Answer (score 0):

From the toolbar...

```
EDIT > Column Properties > Formatting > (Click Custom in Category)
```

Then in the `Format string` box just enter `dd/mm/yy hh:mm`

This will retain your column datatype of `DATETIME` but display it in the manner which you want, in `UK` format.